# Spring STS Maven how to avoid downloading jars from public repositories

Tags: spring, maven, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, pom.xml, repository

I am using Spring STS (sts-springsourcetoolsuite) for development, in my company it is not allowed to download jars from internet/public repositories. In my pom.xml I have not specified public repositories like http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 however it automatically refers to this public repo.

I am not able to understand how to avoid downloading jars from unspecified repositories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have internal maven repository in your company and are only allowed to use that one? Based on [Exclude central repository thread](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Exclude-central-repository-td107349.html) all you have to do is name your internal repository `central` in `settings.xml`.

Comment: There are two locations where a settings.xml file may live:

The Maven install: $M2_HOME/conf/settings.xml
A user's install: ${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml
The former settings.xml are also called global settings, the latter settings.xml are referred to as user settings. If both files exists, their contents gets merged, with the user-specific settings.xml being dominant.